# Проблема с остановкой requestAnimationFrame в ie, edge

Tags: javascript

Есть функция движения объекта за мышкой по оси X. Во всех браузерах, за исключением IE и Edge анимация плавная, в этих двух - анимация не выполняется пока мышь в движении.

Можно переписать функцию с использованием `setInterval` и все будет работать, но мне нужна именно `requestAnimationFrame`, да и в целом неплохо было бы выяснить, что я делаю не так.

```
var animate, block;

block = document.getElementById("block");

animate = function(options) {
  var measure, start;
  start = performance.now();
  return requestAnimationFrame(measure = function(time) {
    var progress, timeFraction;
    timeFraction = (time - start) / options.duration;
    progress = options.timing(timeFraction);
    if (progress < 0) {
      progress = 0;
    }
    if (progress > 1) {
      progress = 1;
    }
    options.draw(progress);
    if (timeFraction < 1) {
      return requestAnimationFrame(measure);
    }
  });
};

block.style.left = getComputedStyle(block).left;

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var dX, lastX, theX;
  lastX = parseInt(block.style.left);
  theX = e.pageX;
  dX = theX / 3 - lastX + 100;
  return animate({
    duration: 100,
    timing: function(timeFraction) {
      return timeFraction;
    },
    draw: function(progress) {
      return block.style.left = (lastX + progress * dX) + "px";
    }
  });
};
```

Код на JSFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/44dkk602/1/

Пояснения к коду:

*animate* - функция анимации, брал из учебника Ильи Кантора с добавлением проверки на отрицательность и выше единицы progress'а.

*lastX* - текущее положение блока

*theX* - текущее положение курсора

*dx* - вычисление расстояния на который нужно сдвинуть блок, где 3 - коэффициент того, на сколько я хочу, чтобы положение блока "отставало" от положения курсора, а 100 - это просто сдвиг всей конструкции немного вправо.

*duration* - продолжительность анимации.

*progress* - изменяется от 0 до 1 за время *duration*.

Comment: FF 40 и IE 11 разницы не заметил. Квадрат двигается рывками вправо-влево за мышью.

Comment: FF 40.0.3 - блок двигается плавно, совсем без рывков. В iE11 - фризит

Comment: возможно разное окружение/железо, отсюда разное поведение скрипта. У меня на FF 40.0.3 Win 7 рывки в обоих браузерах на представленном тесте.

Answer (score 1):

Может лучше как то так? https://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/au4eacwh/

```
var block = document.getElementById('block'),
    raf_id = null,
    active = false,
    pointer_x = 0,
    x = 0;

function calc (e) {
    if (!active) {
        x = block.style.left;
        active = true;
        raf_id = requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }

    pointer_x = e.pageX;
    x = (pointer_x / 3) + 100;
}

function draw () {
    block.style.left = x + 'px';
}

function update () {
    if (raf_id) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(raf_id);
        raf_id = null;
    }

    draw();

    raf_id = requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', calc, false);
```

Comment: В таком случае возникает проблема, при которой блок резко появляется на новом месте, если увести курсор за пределы окна.